# Using declare for referencing variables from an array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, ubuntu, scripting

I am trying to loop through an array of directories using a bash script so I can list directories with their timestamp, ownership etc using `ls -arlt`. I am reviewing bash so would like some feedback.

It works with `declare -a` for those indirect references but for each directory it outputs and extra directory from the /home/user.

I tried to use `declare -n` and `declare -r` for each directory and doesn't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Bash variables
acpi=/etc/acpi
apm=/etc/apm
xml=/etc/xml
array=( acpi apm xml )


# Function to display timestamp, ownership ...
displayInfo()
{
    for i in "${array[@]}"; do
      declare -n curArray=$i
      if [[ -d ${curArray} ]]; then
        declare -a _acpi=${curArray[0]} _apm=${curArray[1]} _xml=${curArray[2]}
        echo "Displaying folder apci: " 
        cd $_acpi
        ls -alrt
        read -p "Press enter to continue"

        echo "Displaying folder apm: " 
        cd $_apm
        ls -alrt
        read -p "Press enter to continue"

        echo "Displaying folder xml: " 
        cd $_xml
        ls -alrt
        read -p "Press enter to continue"
      else
        echo "Displayed Failed" >&2
        exit 1
      fi
    done
}
displayInfo
exit 0
```

It outputs an extra directory listing the /home/user and don't want that output.

Comment: `acpi`, `apm`, and `xml` are plain variables, not arrays; thus, when you point `curArray` at one of them and then try to access it as if it's an array, only `${curArray[0]}` has an actual value. It looks like you're looping over that list of variables, and then for each one looping again over the same things... which doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I have tried `curArray[0]` for ex and still loops twice on that directory which one is correct and the other one is from the /home/user which don't want that.  I still need to pause for each directory.  You got an example?

Comment: Can you explain what you're actually trying to do? Is it just to run `ls -alrt` on each of those three directories?

Comment: Yes I am trying to `ls -alrt` for each of those directories to verify their timestamp, ownership etc ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of complex and powerful shell features being used here, but in ways that don't fit together or make sense. I'll go over the mistakes in a minute, first let me just give how I'd do it. One thing I will use that you might not be familiar with is indirect variable references with `${!var}` -- this is like using a nameref variable, but IMO it's clearer what's going on.

```
acpi=/etc/acpi
apm=/etc/apm
xml=/etc/xml
array=( acpi apm xml )

displayInfo()
{
    for curDirectory in "${array[@]}"; do
        if [[ -d ${!curDirectory} ]]; then
            echo "Displaying folder $curDirectory:" 
            ls -alrt "${!curDirectory}"
            read -p "Press enter to continue"
        else
            echo "Error: ${!curDirectory} does not exist or is not a directory" >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    done
}
displayInfo
```

(One problem with this is that it does the "Press enter to continue" thing after each directory, rather than just between them. This can be fixed, but it's a little more work.)

Ok, now for what went wrong with the original. My main recommendation for you would be to try mentally stepping through your code to see what it's doing. It can help to put `set -x` before it, so the shell will print its interpretation of what it's doing as it runs, and see how it compares to what you expected. Let's do a short walkthrough of the `displayInfo` function:

```
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
```

This will loop over the contents of `array`, so on the first pass through the loop `i` will be set to "acpi". Good so far.

```
declare -n curArray=$i
```

This creates a nameref variable pointing to the other variable `acpi` -- this is similar to what I did with `${! }`, and basically reasonable so far. Well, with one exception: the name suggests it's an array, but `acpi` is a plain variable, not an array.

```
if [[ -d ${curArray} ]]; then
```

This checks whether the contents of the `acpi` variable, "/etc/acpi" is the path of an existing directory (which it is). Still doing good.

```
    declare -a _acpi=${curArray[0]} _apm=${curArray[1]} _xml=${curArray[2]}
```

Here's where things go completely off the rails. `curArray` points to the variable `acpi`, so `${curArray[0]}` etc are equivalent to `${acpi[0]}` etc. But `acpi` isn't an array, it's a plain variable, so `${acpi[0]}` gets its value, and `${acpi[1]}` and `${acpi[2]}` get *nothing*. Furthermore, you're using `declare -a` (declare arrays), but you're just assigning single values to `_acpi`, `_apm`, and `_xml`. They're declared as arrays, but you're just using them as plain variables (basically the reverse of how you're using `curArray` -> `acpi`).

There's a deeper confusion here as well. The `for` loop above is iterating over "acpi", "apm", and "xml", and we're currently working on "acpi". During this pass through the loop, you should *only* be working on acpi, not *also* trying to work on apm and xml. That's the point of having a `for` loop there.

Ok, that's the main problem here, but let me just point out a couple of other things I'd consider bad practice:

```
    cd $_apm
    ls -alrt
```

Using a variable reference without double-quotes around it like this invites parsing confusion; you should almost always put double-quotes, like `cd "$_apm"`. Also, using `cd` in a script is dangerous because if it fails the rest of the script will execute in the wrong place. In this case, `_apm` is empty, so without double-quotes it's equivalent to just `cd`, which moves to your home directory. This is why you're getting that result. If you used `cd "$_apm"` it would get an error instead... but since you don't check for that it'll go ahead and still list an irrelevant location.

It's almost always better to avoid `cd` and its complications entirely, and just use explicit paths, like `ls -alrt "$_apm"`.

```
echo "Displayed Failed" >&2
exit 1
```

Do you actually want to exit the entire script if one of the directories doesn't exist? It'd make more sense to me to just `return 1` (which exits just the function, not the entire script), or better yet `continue` (which just goes on to the next iteration of the loop -- i.e. the next directory on the list). I left the `exit` in my version, but I'd recommend changing it.

One more similar thing:

```
acpi=/etc/acpi
apm=/etc/apm
xml=/etc/xml
array=( acpi apm xml )
```

Is there any actual reason to use this array -> variable name -> actual directory path system (and resulting indirect expansion or nameref complications), rather than just having an array of directory paths, like this?

```
array=( /etc/acpi /etc/apm /etc/xml )
```

I left the indirection in my version above, but really if there's no reason for it I'd remove the complication.

Comment: I tried `array=( /etc/acpi /etc/apm /etc/xml )` and it outputs bad substitution, so prob I should stick to indirect expansion

Comment: @user2537246 with `array=( /etc/acpi /etc/apm /etc/xml )`, remove all the indirect expansions. That is, use "${curDirectory}" everywhere instead of `"${!curDirectory}"`.